# Using GoogleSignInClient with libGDX and RelativeLayout causes GoogleSignInIntent to display repeatedly and return error code 13

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-signin, google-play-games

I am attempting to implement Google Play Game Services into the Android backend of my libGDX game. I used the same implementation (same helper methods, private classes, etc) as the TypeANumber module in the android-basic-samples, Google's official examples for implementing Google Play Game Services, with one main difference. In my signInSilently helper method, I changed it so that if the silentSignIn task fails, the method calls startSignIn (starts sign in intent with interactive UI) instead of onDisconnected (which sets the AchievementClient, LeaderBoardClient, and PlayersClient to null).

I did this because in a lot of games I've seen (ie Dune!), they often try the silentSignIn and start the SignIn intent if the silentSignIn is unsuccessful. However, now, whenever I start my game, the silentSignIn fails and defaults to the interactive UI. But the UI appears to fail and start up repeatedly, only to fail again and the user is flooded with AlertDialogs indicating that the error code is 13.

I'm not really sure what I've done wrong and I'm wondering how I'm correctly supposed to implement Google Play Game Services. I am using Admob so I have a RelativeLayout and I do have all my ID's in a games-ids.xml file.

onConnected helper method

```
private void onConnected(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
        mAchievementsClient = Games.getAchievementsClient(this, 
googleSignInAccount);
        mLeaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, 
googleSignInAccount);
        mPlayersClient = Games.getPlayersClient(this, 
googleSignInAccount);

        // Set the greeting appropriately on main menu
        mPlayersClient.getCurrentPlayer()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Player>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Player> task) {
                        String displayName;
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            displayName = task.getResult().getDisplayName();
                        } else {
                            displayName = "???";
                        }
                    }
                })
        ;
```

onDisconnected helper method

```
private void onDisconnected() {
    mAchievementsClient = null;
    mLeaderboardsClient = null;
    mPlayersClient = null;
}
```

startSignInIntent helper method

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
    startActivityForResult(mSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

signInSilently helper method

```
private void signInSilently() {
    mSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // The signed in account is stored in the task's result.
                onConnected(task.getResult());
            } else {
                //Use interactive UI to sign player in
                startSignInIntent();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

onActivityResult override

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task =
                GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent);

        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            onConnected(account);
        } catch (ApiException apiException) {
            String message = apiException.getMessage();
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = SIGNIN_OTHER_ERROR;
            }

            onDisconnected();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

onCreate override

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build());

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useAccelerometer = false;
    config.useCompass = false;

    //replaces initialize()
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    mAdViewTopBanner = createAdView(AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER_TOP, ADVIEW_ID, RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    View gameView = createGameView(config);
    layout.addView(gameView);
    layout.addView(mAdViewTopBanner);

    setContentView(layout);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, AD_APP_ID);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL);
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });

    mAdViewTopBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mAdViewTopBanner.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}
```

onActivityResult ovverride

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task =
                GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent);

        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            onConnected(account);
        } catch (ApiException apiException) {
            String message = apiException.getMessage();
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = SIGNIN_OTHER_ERROR;
            }

            onDisconnected();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

onResume override

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    signInSilently();
    mAdViewTopBanner.resume();
}
```

I know it's a lot of code to read through so huge thank you for helping out!

Comment: Can you please attempt to turn this into a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: As an additional reference, you may also want to [quality check](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist) your work to check what's missing or what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You must not call the non-silent login methods on game start. It is no valid reason to do something wrong just because others also do wrong. If you do it this way, your game will not be useable on devices without with outdated Play Services or without GPGS app.

For using Play Games with libGDX, you can use [my extension](https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-gamesvcs). If you don't want to use it for whatever reasons, pick the working code from [GpgsClient class](https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-gamesvcs/blob/master/android-gpgs/src/de/golfgl/gdxgamesvcs/GpgsClient.java).

Comment: I installed your plugin, defining the API version right after the gdxVersion and adding the corresponding dependency to the core project. I also added a GdxGameSvcsApp.gwt.xml file in /core/src like you did in the demo project but when importing the libraries into my Game class, the libraries couldn't be recognized (ie Cannot resolve symbol 'IGameServiceClient').